# How to stop key Down of the form

Tags: c#

I have a `Form1_KeyDown` event for `form1`, but while I am typing some text in the Textbox on the Form, the event gets triggered.

How can I stop that event when I am typing inside the textboxes on the form.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use on blur event instead of keyDown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Set form's KeyPreview to false. Which is the default, so you must have explicitly changed it, presumably for a reason. Otherwise the controls of on the form always get the keyboard events first.
2. Add an active control check in `Form1_KeyDown`, like this:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ActiveControl == textBox1) return;
    var k = e.KeyCode;
}
```